# How to find the best number of integers with fewer repeated values sequentially in Python

Tags: python

```
A = [7, 3, 7, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1]
```

> I have a variable containing a list of integers. These integers show the location,

7 = USA

3 = UAE

1 = India

4 = Pakistan

If I have five location to visit in each day, how do I get the best five days in sequence for less repetition?

For example, I want the output array of [7,3,1,3,4] from 7 to 4 these 5 locations are most unique just 1 repeated from the array sequence, I just get 1 repeated location, which is 3, so dynamically, is it possible to get the output when i change the number of locations?

Comment: "If I have five days to visit each location, how do I get the best five days in sequence for less repetition?" - Is there a constraint on your list of integers that guarantees that it is possible to visit a sequence of all locations within 5 days? " is it possible to get the output when i change the number of locations?" - only if you have some constraints on your data. Otherwise you run into a variant of The Traveling Salesman Problem. The main issue is you may not have any guarantee that the data even has a solution for visiting all locations in 5 days.

Comment: What determines the "best sequence"?  e.g. Why is `[7, 3, 1, 3, 4]` better than `[7, 7, 1, 3, 4]` or `[7, 3, 1, 4, 1]`?

Comment: because i cant change the sequence which is defined in the list.

Comment: this is better because its original sequence [7, 3, 1, 3, 4] and this is [7, 7, 1, 3, 4] rearranged from original list, there is no any sequence like [7, 7, 1, 3, 4]

Comment: But how is `[7, 3, 1, 3, 4]` not rearranged, but `[7, 7, 1, 3, 4]` is?

Comment: A = [7, 3, 7, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1] this is the original list
[7, 3, 1, 3, 4] is start from 7 ends with 4 so its not rearranged

Comment: but `[7, 7, 1, 3, 4]` starts from `7` and ends with `4`.

Comment: [7, 7, 1, 3, 4] is not in this array A = [7, 3, 7, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1] it starts from 7 but between of both 7 there is a number 3

Comment: So you are looking for a slice of `A` with all elements present and minimal length?

Comment: Sure it is: `[7, 7, 1, 3, 4]` takes number from the original list, from indexes `0`, `2`, `4`, `5` and `6`.

Comment: i dont know how to achieve this. but i need the data between start location mean 7 and end location mean 4, it should come dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I'm understanding the problem correctly, you're trying to go through a table and find the capture that has the most unique numbers

eg:

[image: example]

You can do this pretty simply

```py
A = [7, 3, 7, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1]

most_unique = []
for start in range(len(A)-4): # making sure not to go out of the table bounds
    capture = A[start:start+5]
    if len(set(capture)) > len(set(most_unique)): #using a set() which removes duplicates and checking the length of it
        most_unique = capture

print(most_unique)
```

---

As per comments, the OP requested for a solution that is dynamic and determines the amount of days with the most unique numberset

```py
A = [7, 3, 7, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1]

most_unique = []
for size in range(len(A)): # loops through all the possible day amounts
    for start in range(len(A)-size+1): # making sure not to go out of the table bounds
        capture = A[start:start+size]
        if len(set(capture)) > len(set(most_unique)): #using a set() which removes duplicates and checking the length of it
            most_unique = capture

print(most_unique)
```

Comment: But here is a problem: you specified the number of days as 5. I want this to be fully dynamic. I mean, the program should decide that from index 7 or else to index 4 or else the most unique numbers.

Comment: So your goal is to find the smallest amount of days that has the most unique numbers?

Comment: my goal is to find the largest amount of days that has the most unique numbers?

Comment: I've edited my original post to provide a solution that loops through all the day sets to find the set with the most unique numbers @azhar

Answer (score 0):

So if you mean a slice from A of length 5 (ie days) then, since `len(A) == 8`, then there are only a few possible slices.

I would just enumerate all the slices and pick one with the fewest repeats (or the largest number of different locations):

```py
def find_best_sequence(seq, days):
    num_slices = len(seq) - days + 1

    trials = []
    for index in range(num_slices):
        s = seq[index:index+days]
        trials.append((s,set(s)))

    trials.sort(key=lambda x:-len(x[1]))
    return trials

seq = [7, 3, 7, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1]

days = 5

trials = find_best_sequence(seq, days)
print(trials[0][0])
```

Output as requested